# Godot gdnative Rust access property defined in the editor

Tags: rust, godot, gdnative

In order to learn about the engine I'm trying my hand at a very simple project - proceduraly generating a sphere using the editor and the gdnative Rust bindings.
I'm trying to follow up [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaEtBrI3qdc) which uses GDScript and convert the
code to Rust.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to access a property defined in the editor.
I've been reading the docs and searching around the web for a week now but there is
something that escapes me and I'm not able to arrive at an understanding of how to proceed about it.

What I want to do, is access the `mesh` property, of type ArrayMesh, much like in the tutorial that I linked above, and attach to it the arrays that I generated for the vertices - basically bind those arrays to the ArrayMesh. Here is my scene:

```
[gd_scene load_steps=4 format=2]

[ext_resource path="res://procedural_earth.gdnlib" type="GDNativeLibrary" id=1]

[sub_resource type="ArrayMesh" id=4]

[sub_resource type="NativeScript" id=3]
resource_name = "ProcEarth"
class_name = "ProcEarth"
library = ExtResource( 1 )

[node name="Earth" type="Spatial"]

[node name="Sphere" type="MeshInstance" parent="."]
mesh = SubResource( 4 )
script = SubResource( 3 )

[node name="Camera" type="Camera" parent="."]
transform = Transform( 0.572229, -0.327396, 0.751909, 0, 0.916856, 0.399217, -0.820094, -0.228443, 0.524651, 4.71648, 2.5, 3.45846 )
current = true
```

The ArrayMesh structure that I'm interested in, is called `mesh` in the above scene and is part of the node named "Sphere"(mentioning just for the sake of clarity).

I have the following Rust code:

```
#[derive(NativeClass)]
#[inherit(MeshInstance)]
#[register_with(register_properties)]
struct ProcEarth {
     // ...
}  

impl ProcEarth {

    // ...

   #[export]
   fn _ready(&mut self, owner: &MeshInstance) {

       let mut arr = VariantArray::new_shared();
       // ...
       let blend_shapes = VariantArray::new_shared();
       owner.add_surface_from_arrays(Mesh::PRIMITIVE_TRIANGLES, arr, blend_shapes, 0);
   }
}
```

But that does not work as the error I get is:

```
no method named `add_surface_from_arrays` found for reference `&gdnative::gdnative_bindings::MeshInstance` in the current scope

method not found in `&gdnative::gdnative_bindings::MeshInstance`rustc(E0599)
```

Does anyone know how could I access in the Rust code that property from the editor, in order to properly set my ArrayMesh? Is there any tutorial, article, video that exemplifies that?

Any pointers highly appreciated as I'm currently stuck into this technicality
and cannot progress my learning.

I'm using Godot version v3.4.stable.official with gdnative 0.9.3 on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [`add_surface_from_arrays`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_arraymesh.html#class-arraymesh-method-add-surface-from-arrays) is defined in `ArrayMesh`. Given the error you got, you are trying to call it on a `MeshInstance`.

We can confirm that with the source code, since you get `owner: &MeshInstance` and you are calling `owner.add_surface_from_arrays(…)`.

Usually you would create an `ArrayMesh` and call `add_surface_from_arrays` on it passing an array with the vertex data. Afterwards you should be able to call [`set_mesh`](https://godot-rust.github.io/docs/gdnative/api/struct.MeshInstance.html#method.set_mesh) on the `MeshInstance` passing the `ArrayMesh`.

```
let mut am = ArrayMesh::new();
let mut arr = VariantArray::new_shared();
// …
let blend_shapes = VariantArray::new_shared();
am.add_surface_from_arrays(Mesh::PRIMITIVE_TRIANGLES, arr, blend_shapes, 0);
owner.set_mesh(am.cast::<Mesh>());
```

I believe you can call [`mesh`](https://godot-rust.github.io/docs/gdnative/api/struct.MeshInstance.html#method.mesh) on the `MeshInstance` to retrieve it. Be aware that it can a `Mesh` (`ArrayMesh` or `PrimitiveMesh`) or nil. *The method `mesh` is documented to return `Option<Ref<Mesh, Shared>>`.*

Comment: Thank you! That steered me in the correct direction. Calling "mesh" is the way to go for getting the ArrayMesh instance defined in the editor.